# Is there a more durable way to catch washing machine lint?

Tags: washing-machine, laundry

Our washing machine drains to a utility sink, which was regularly clogging with lint until I started keeping a nylon stocking around the hose outlet. That works fine, but after a month or two the stocking is so clogged with slimy lint that I have to invert it and scrape the lint off. Or it just tears altogether.

It seems wasteful to go through nylons like this, but all of the washing machine lint traps I see for sale online appear to be similarly disposable. Is there a way to catch lint coming out of the drain hose that doesn't involve swapping out disposable filters/nylons?

Is there something I can build that will be more straightforward to clean the lint paste scum off of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We purchased a washable filter for the drain of our washing machine, not so much as to prevent clogging the utility sink (separate drain) but to protect the septic tank and drain field.

I understand that this is not a proper location for recommendations, but if you search for filtrol 160, you may be in luck. I purchased a second filter sock for the unit, allowing me to wash off the more recently used filter while a fresh one is placed.

Clearly you won't want to rinse the filter off in your utility sink, or in any location which may continue the clogging problem. I wait until the weather is good, turn the sock inside out and hose it with the garden hose on high pressure stream. The gunk in the sock is mostly dirt, although there's likely some synthetic fibers. I don't think there's enough to be an environmental concern when washed while outside.